# Pulling a Sub-String in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this code that generates the following output:

```
$String = "shutdown.exe -r -f"
$Data = schtasks /query /v /fo LIST | Select-String $String -Context 7 -SimpleMatch | Out-File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\String.txt"
$Testy = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\String.txt'

Get-Content $Testy | select-string 'TaskName' -SimpleMatch -OutVariable $Taskname
Write-Host $Taskname

Output= TaskName:                             \FWI Reboot
```

I need to find a way to isolate `FWI Reboot`. How can I do that?

Comment: `Write-Host $taskName.Split(':')[1].Trim()`

Comment: I added that to the bottom of my code and generated:

Comment: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: This is a round-about way for me to extract the name of the daily reboot task on our pool of computers. I'm able to get that split to work in a separate test, so I'm thinking my $Taskname isn't a string?

Comment: What version of powershell? If possible you should be using Get-ScheduledTask instead of trying to parse string output.

Comment: Unfortunately this needs to be ran on a mixture of Win7/Win10 machines. Get-ScheduledTask doesn't exist on Win7 from what I understand.

Comment: `Get-ScheduledTask` may not be available, but the [Task Scheduler 2.0 COM API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383665(v=vs.85).aspx) is. The example is for VBScript, but it's not too complicated to convert it to PowerShell. Definitely beats parsing information out of text output.

Comment: I finally got this to work with the first comment. I think that my problem was the file wasn't being read as a string. Thanks for the help guys!